# Is the empty string a subtring of all strings?

Tags: javascript

I've been designing a search bar function that removes results that do not include the value of the user input. So far it's been successful, but when the user enters an empty string, I want it to return back to default and reverse all of the hidden posts. And while it does work, I wanted to ask the question if all strings contain a substring "" which is empty as it would help my understanding.

Here is what I mean:

```
let strArray = ['Hello', 'w', '324551', ''];

for (var i=0; i<strArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(strArray[i].indexOf("") !== -1);
}

Output: 
    True
    True
    True
    True
```

This may be a simple question to answer for some, but I'd just like clarification to reason my work.

Comment: It looks like you already answered the question for yourself by writing that test. Well done! Here's another way: `console.log('hello world'.includes('')); // true`

Comment: @jsejcksn Yeah it seemed like it was true, but I just wanted that extra confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: Even the NUL character contains an empty string: `String.fromCharCode(0x00).indexOf("") === 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. From [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-stringindexof):

> 2. If searchValue is the empty String and `fromIndex ≤ len`, return fromIndex.

Where `fromIndex` is almost always 0. (It will only not be 0 if you pass a second optional parameter to `indexOf`)

Comment: Thanks. I'll be sure to accept this an answer as soon as it's available.